# Signing and Verifying of Signature using Pycryptodome always fails

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, rsa, pycryptodome

Hi I'm using the Pycryptodome package to try and verify signatures of transactions in a Blockchain. My issue is that when trying to add a new transaction, I first create a signature to be passed into a verify transaction method but for some reason it always fails even though the logic seems to be right when I compare it to the documentation. If anyone could point me where I'm going wrong it would be much appreciated. I have 3 methods that handle all of this and i'm not sure where the issue is

The generate keys method

```
def generate_keys(self):
        # generate private key pair
        private_key = RSA.generate(1024, Crypto.Random.new().read)

        # public key comes as part of private key generation
        public_key = private_key.publickey()

        # return keys as hexidecimal representation of binary data
        return (binascii.hexlify(public_key.exportKey(format='DER')).decode('ascii'), binascii.hexlify(private_key.exportKey(format='DER')).decode('ascii'))
```

The sign transaction method

```
def sign_transaction(self, sender, recipient, amount, key):

        # convert transaction data to SHA256 string
        hash_signer = SHA256.new(
            (str(sender) + str(recipient) + str(amount)).encode('utf-8'))

        # sign transaction
        signature = pkcs1_15.new(RSA.importKey(
            binascii.unhexlify(key))).sign(hash_signer)


        # return hexidecimal representation of signature
        return binascii.hexlify(signature).decode('ascii')
```

and the verify transaction method

```
@staticmethod
def verify_transaction(transaction):
        # convert public key back to binary representation
        public_key = RSA.importKey(binascii.unhexlify(
            transaction.sender))

        try:
            # create signature from transaction data
            hash_signer = SHA256.new(
                (str(transaction.sender) + str(transaction.recipient) + str(transaction.amount)).encode('utf-8'))


            pkcs1_15.new(public_key).verify(
                hash_signer, binascii.unhexlify(transaction.signature))


            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
```

Once i've generated my key pair and attempt to use them to sign and verify transactions it always fails. I know this because it always returns false from the verify method leading me to believe a value error is always raised. Thanks in advance hopefully someone can help me out.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Does `sender` really contain the public key when signing and verifying?

Comment: Yeah sender contains the public key, so your saying it works ok for you?

Comment: Yes, I've used [this code](https://pastebin.com/wPamgXCr) which can be executed e.g. [here](https://repl.it/languages/python3).